# Finding lowest possible value for conditional set of variables.

Tags: word-problem

I came across the following problem and am having trouble solving it. I believe I have come across the first insight into how to solve the problem but I am having trouble seeing the second insight.

The problem is as follows:

Suppose you have 5 positive sequential integers $$ r, o, h, a, n. $$ The sum of $$ o + h + a $$ is a perfect square. The sum of $$ r + o + h + a + n $$ is a perfect cube. What is the lowest possible value of h?

So my first insight is as follows:

$$ r + o + h + a + n = r + (r+1) + (r+2) + (r+3) + (r+4) = 5r+10 $$
$$ \implies 3r+6=y^2 $$
$$ and, 5r+10=x^3. $$

I am unsure how to combine these functions or use them to find a minimum, since they do not share an x or y.

Any hints/suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I made an error in transposing the problem. The variables are not defined to be "sequential positive integers", but as "consecutive positive integers". I am unsure if this implies a variable range between the numbers or not.

If it does, I get the answer of:

$$ r=1, o=2, h=3, a=4, n=17 $$

I cannot imagine a lesser solution since r is the lowest possible positive integer and o and h increase by 1 each time. However, my answer is not correct. Does "consecutive positive integers" imply a uniform range between each number?

Comment: Yes, consecutive means that any two neighbors differ by 1.  So 1,2,3 are consecutive integers, but 1,3,4 are not consecutive.

Comment: This is a buttinsky as it doesn't change anything.  rather than doing things in terms of r, do them in terms of a h.  That way when you say o+h+a = 3r + 6, you would simply have have o + h + a = 3h, and instead of r + o + h + a +n = 5r + 10, you'd simply have r + o + h + a +n = 5h.  It won't change anything but it makes the arithmetic less irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier, I think, to write the sequence as $$\{h-2,h-1,h,h+1,h+2\}$$

Then the conditions are $$3h=n^2\;\;and\;\;5h=m^3$$

Clearly $ord_3(h)$ must be an odd multiple of $3$, and $ord_5(h)$ must be even and congruent to $-1\,mod(3)$.  (we also know that $6|ord_p(h)$ for all other primes, but for the minimal $h$ we will just zero all of those out).  It follows that the smallest suitable $h$ is $h=3^35^2=675$.

For avoidance of doubt:  In the above $ord_p(h)$ refers simply to the greatest power of $p$ dividing $h$.  Thanks to a commenter (@joriki) for pointing out another (unintended) use of that notation.

Comment: It seems you're using $\operatorname{ord}_n(h)$ with a different meaning from [this convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order)?

Comment: Indeed I am!  When did that change?  For me, $ord_p(n)$ means the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$. How does one refer to that these days?

Comment: @joriki  I have some support, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116356/what-is-the-meaning-of-operatornameord-pn

Comment: I see. We should tell Wikipedia about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your first two insights are good.  Let's keep going, though.  Rearrange your equations $3r +6 = y^2$ and $5r + 10 = x^3$ to get $r = \frac{1}{3}(y^2 - 6)$ and $r = \frac{1}{5}(x^3 - 10)$.  Then we get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{y^2}{3} - 2 = \frac{x^3}{5} - 2
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\frac{y^2}{3}= \frac{x^3}{5}.
\end{equation}
I believe that the lowest integer solution to this occurs when $x=15$ and $y=45$ (thank you to @joriki for pointing that out!).  We can then find $r = 673$, and then $h = 675$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that confirmation. However, I apparently did not transpose the problem correctly! Please see my edit.

Comment: How about $x=15$, $y=45$, $r=673$?

Comment: @joriki Thanks.  You're completely correct.

Comment: @joriki Did you find your answer using an approach similar to the one described by lulu? If not, what was your approach?

Comment: @d0rmLife: Somewhat similar, but less formalized -- I just multiplied through by $3$ and $5$ and then kept adding factors of $3$ or $5$ to $x$ or $y$ as long as one side had too few of them.

Answer (score 0):

Cute puzzle!

$o + h + a = h - 1 + h + h + 1 = 3h = v^2$.

So $3$ divides $v$.

$h = 3\times v\times\dfrac v3$

so $3$ divides $h$.

Similarly $r + o + h + a + n = 5h = w^3$.

so $5$ divides $w$.

so $h = 25\times w\times\left(\dfrac w5\right)^2$.

so $25$ divides $h$.

so $75=3\times25$ divides $h$.

but if $3$ divides $h$ then $5\times3\times\frac h3 = w^3$. so $3$ divides $w$. so

$5h = 27\left(\dfrac w3\right)^3$.

So $27$ divides $h$ and $25$ divides $h$ so $h = 27\times25$ is the lowest possible $h$.  That is, *if* $h = 27\times25$ is a solution.  If so:

$o + h + a = 3h = 3\times27\times25 = (9\times5)^2$

$r + o + h + a + n = 5h = 5\times27\times25 = (3\times5)^5$.

So that's it.  $r = 27\times25 - 2, o = 27\times25 -1, a = 27\times25 + 1, n = 27\times25 + 2$, etc.

Comment: $3h=v^2$ and $h=3\cdot v\cdot(v/3)$ don't fit together.