# Show that the order of $a\times b$ is equal to $nm$ if gcd(n,m)=1

Tags: group-theory

$(G,*)$ is an abelian group and $a,b$ are elements of G. Let $n=ord(a)$ and $m=ord(b)$ in $G$. Show that the order of $a*b$ is equal to $nm$ if $gcd(n,m)=1$.

I have already proved that $ord(a*b)|nm$. But the other part is a problem.

Thanks

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/order-of-elements-in-abelian-groups.

Comment: but in the first link, they state (at the end) that the result  is false, so it must be a different question I think.

Comment: If the group is $(G,*)$ you should use $*$ and not $\times$.

Comment: yes, someone has edited I think. I will change it.

Comment: This question is closed as a duplicate to a question that asks to prove a different and **false** statement. Not really helpful. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\text{lcm}(m,n)=mn$, so it suffices to show that $\text{ord}(a*b)$ is a multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have found it.