# If $|x|, |y|$ are finite in a group $G$ and they commute with each other then $|x^r y^s|=LCM(|x^r|, |y^s|)$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

This question occurred to me while studying order of elements in finite group theory. The question which I was solving was: if $|x|=12, |y|=15$ in some Abelian group, what would be the order of $x^{8} y^{9}$. Based on it, the following generalization was developed.

**Let $x, y\in G$ be of finite orders and $xy=yx$. Show order of $x^r y^s$ is the least common multiple of $|x^r|$ and $|y^s|$.**

I tried to prove it but not getting any clue. Any help would be appreciated. In case if any modification needed for correcting the question, you are most welcome.

Comment: This problem reduces to the case $r=s=1$.  Can you prove it in that case?  Can you prove that under your hypotheses, $\forall n \in \Bbb N~((xy)^n=x^ny^n)$?  The latter statement is easily proved by induction on $n$.

Comment: You will probably need to impose some additional condition on $x$ and $y$ in the general statement, since the statement won’t necessarily work if $y=x^{-1}$ (for instance).

Comment: @RobertShore I think yes I can. Since $n$ is a positive integer, by using induction principle we can show the identity.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10616/104041) is a better duplicate, sorry.