# Are all extensions of finite fields cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book says all extensions of finite fields are cyclic, but I could not find a proof (maybe I haven't looked hard enough).  If it's straightforward, can you tell me why it's true?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not sure that the cyclicity of the unit group of a finite field is being used here.  (Not that I have any problem using it: see e.g. Section 2 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400algebra2point5.pdf) for a proof.)

Let $K/\mathbb{F}_q$ be a field extension of degree $n$, so $\# K = q^n$.  Let $\sigma: K \rightarrow K$ be $x \mapsto x^q$. Recall:

> (Lagrange's Little Theorem): Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and
> $g \in G$.  Then the order of $g$ divides $n$.

> The point is that LLT is a special case of Lagrange's Theorem which can be proved by the same argument which proves Fermat's Little Theorem -- i.e., the special case in which $G = \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$.  So one need not talk about cosets and such...

Let $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$.  I claim that $x^q = x$.  This is clear if $x = 0$, and otherwise apply LLT to $x \in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ to get $x^{q-1} = 1$, which implies $x^q = x$.

Therefore $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $K/\mathbb{F}_q$.  As for its order, suppose
$\sigma^i$ is equal to the identity: that is, for all $x \in K$, $x^{q^i} = x$.  We have $P_i(t) = t^{q^i} - t \in K[t]$ is a polynomial of degree $q^i$ over the field $K$, so by the Root-Factor Theorem (a consequence of the division algorithm for polynomials), $P_i(t)$ has at most $q^i$ roots.  It follows that the order of $\sigma$ is equal to $n = \log_q(\# K)$.  Thus the cyclic group generated by $\sigma$ is a degree $n$ subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/\mathbb{F}_q)$.  But by basic Galois theory, for an extension $K/F$ of degree $n$, we have $\# \operatorname{Aut}(K/F) \leq n$, with equality holding if and only if $K/F$ is Galois.  Therefore $K/\mathbb{F}_q$
is a cyclic Galois extension.

If we like, we can now establish that there is a **unique** cyclic extension of degree $n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$: we can take
the splitting field of $t^{q^n} - t$, and splitting fields exist and are unique up to (nonunique) isomorphism over the ground field.

It seems to me that I have not used the cyclicity of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ anywhere...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : $G$ need not be abelian for FLT to hold , right ?

Comment: @Theorem: I'm not sure what "FLT" stands for here.  Definitely Lagrange's Theorem holds for all finite groups.  But the proof which generalizes the standard proof of Fermat's Little Theorem (hmm, FLT?) works only for finite abelian groups.  So far as I know, in order to prove Lagrange's Theorem in the nonabelian case one needs to discuss cosets.

Answer (score 21):

Any *finite* extension of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic. For such an extension $K$ first recall that the Frobenius map $x \mapsto x^q$ is an $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear endomorphism. If $x^q = y^q$ then $(x - y)^q = 0$, hence $x = y$, so the Frobenius map is injective. Since it is an injective linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself, it is surjective, so it is an automorphism. Its fixed field is the subfield of roots of $x^q - x$, which are precisely the elements of the base field $\mathbb{F}_q$. It follows that $K$ is Galois with Galois group the cyclic group generated by $x \mapsto x^q$.

(I guess when I say $\mathbb{F}_q$ I am being mildly circular. Interpret the above proof as follows: any finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is cyclic, and in fact the above proof shows that they are all of the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ using the fact that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, so finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ really do have Frobenius maps like I just claimed they do, and then apply the proof again to $\mathbb{F}_q$.)

Comment: How about *algebraic but infinite* extensions of a finite field ?

Comment: @Fardad: they are "topologically cyclic" in the sense that the subgroup of the Galois group generated by the Frobenius map is dense.

Comment: What about finite extensions of an infinite field?

Answer (score 17):

Below is a *complete, noncircular* simple proof of the result mentioned by Qiaochu that avoids invoking the high-powered structure theorem for finite abelian groups.

**Theorem** $\ $ A finite subgroup $\rm\:G\:$ of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

**Proof** $\ $ By the lemma below $\rm\, x^m = 1\,$  has  $\rm\,\#G\,$ roots, with  $\rm\,m = maxord(G) = expt(G).\,$ A polynomial $\rm\,f\,$ over a field has $\rm\,\#roots\ f \le deg\ f\,$  so $\rm\, \#G \le m.\,$ The maxorder $\rm\,m \le \#G\,$  since  $\rm\,g^{\#G}\! = 1\,$ for all $\rm\,g \in G\,$ (Lagrange). $\,$ So $\rm\,m = \#G = maxord(G),\,$ so $\rm\,G\,$ has an elt of order $\rm\#G$.

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm{\bf Lemma}\qquad maxord(G) &=&\,\rm expt(G)\ \text{ for a finite abelian group}\ G,\ i.e.\\[.5em] 
\rm max\ \{ ord(g) : \: g \in G\} &=&\,\rm  min\ \{ n>0 : \: g^n = 1\ \ \forall\ g \in G\}\end{eqnarray}$

**Proof** $\ $ See this [Oct 2010 answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6856/242) for a short simple proof (hint: show that a finite abelian group has an *lcm closed* order set).

Comment: I think the OP was asking if the (finite) extension $K/\mathbb{F}_q$ is a cyclic *extension*, namely that $\mbox{Gal}(K/\mathbb{F}_q)$ is a cyclic group. Does this immediately follow from the fact that $K^\times$ is a cyclic group?

Comment: @Alon I've edited it to clarify that it was meant to support Qiaochu's answer.