# Question about existence of Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm confused about the distinction between these two:

For a field $F$ and a finite group $G$, we can find a galois extension $E/F$ with galois group $G$.

Given a finite group $G$, there exists a field $F$ and a galois extension $E/F$ with galois group $G$.

What's the distinction between these statements and are they both true?

Comment: @rogerl The second question is quite easy to answer in the affirmative. The first question is unsolved for $F=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Indeed, @LordSharktheUnknown, as I know you know, for certain fields $F$ (like the finite fields), the first statement is resoundingly false.

Comment: Could you give me an example why it fails with $F$ finite fields or $/mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3):

The first statement is a generalized statement of the [Inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).  For this, the field $F$ is fixed and cannot be chosen.  The second statement removes the restriction: $F$ can be any field.

If we set $F = \mathbb{Q}$, the first statement is unknown save for a few choices of $G$.  On the other hand, this statement fails when $F$ is a finite field because [every Galois extension will have a cyclic Galois group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38197/are-all-extensions-of-finite-fields-cyclic): *only* $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will appear as a Galois group (for any $n \in \mathbb{N})$.

However, the second statement *is true* for any finite group $G$.  To see this, first recall [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), which states that any finite group $G$ appears as a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n \geq |G|$.  Next, [Hilbert proved that $S_n$ appears as a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Symmetric_and_alternating_groups); let $K$ be a Galois extension with $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_n$.  Finally, the [Galois correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory#Explicit_description_of_the_correspondence) tells us that, for each subgroup $H$ of $S_n$, there will exist an intermediate field $\mathbb{Q} \subset E_H \subset K$ such that the subgroup is isomorphic to $\text{Gal}(K/E_H)$.  This is to say, $G$ will appear as the Galois group for the extension $K/E_G$.